# Spring Cloud Contract Content type not supported

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract, contract

I am using spring cloud contract and I am getting the error

```bash
    2020-06-23 23:27:41.940  WARN 39531 --- 
    [main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: 
    Content type 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1' not supported]
```

I am not sure if I am missing anything. I have tried several things and read the documentation several times and I cannot find the issue. I have also successfully used spring cloud contracts in the past (In my old job, don't have the code anymore) Maybe there is a problem of compatibility with the newer versions?  Here are the classes I am using:

**Controller**

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/names")
    public class NameController {
    
        @PostMapping
        public Name addName(@RequestBody Name name) {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

**Entity (Name)**

```java
    @Data
    public class Name {
    
        private Long id;
        private String name;
    
    }
```

**BaseClass for set up**

```java
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
    @DirtiesContext
    @AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
    public class BaseClass {
    
        @Autowired
        private NameController nameController;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
    
            StandaloneMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(nameController);
            RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(builder);
        }
    }
```

**create_name.groovy**

```json
    Contract.make {
    
        request {
            url '/names'
            method 'POST'
            headers {
                contentType(applicationJson())
            }
            body([
                    id  : 1,
                    name: "hello"
            ])
        }
        response {
            status OK()
        }
    }
```

Also here is the generated test

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public class ContractVerifierTest extends BaseClass {
    
        @Test
        public void validate_create_name() throws Exception {
            // given:
                MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .body("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"hello\"}");
    
            // when:
                ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                        .post("/names");
    
            // then:
                assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have started my search in the Github repository. This seems to be a known issue here is the link: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1428

Here is how my working test base class looks.

```java
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
    public class BaseClass {
    
        @Autowired
        private NameController nameController;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
    
            EncoderConfig encoderConfig = new EncoderConfig(Charsets.UTF_8.name(), Charsets.UTF_8.name());
            RestAssuredMockMvc.config = new RestAssuredMockMvcConfig().encoderConfig(encoderConfig);
    
            StandaloneMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(nameController);
    
            RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(builder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fix problem without configuring mockMvc, just add UTF-8 to Content-Type header, like

```
headers {
        contentType('application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    }
```

[image: log]